# draw one item from a collection in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new in java and learning from a tutorial in the web and I am stuck with this code.

```
for (SimpleButton playButton : menuButtons) {playButton.draw(batcher);}
```

This code draws all buttons from the list. How can I draw only one button from the list that I created? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure of the number of elements in the list, you can always access it with the items index.

```
menuButtons.get(0)
```

returns your first item.

So basically `menuButtons.get(i)` where `i` is the requested index of the element.
Be sure to not try and access an index higher than the size of the list.

You can then call .draw directly on the element returned:

```
menuButtons.get(i).draw(batcher);
```